# Infix format for Nemerle macro

Tags: metaprogramming, dsl, nemerle

Say I need some very special multiplication operator. It may be implemented in following macro:

```
macro @<<!(op1, op2)
{
    <[ ( $op1 * $op2 ) ]>
}
```

And I can use it like

```
def val = 2 <<! 3
```

And its work.

But what I really want is some 'english'-like operator for the DSL Im developing now:

```
macro @multiply(op1, op2)
{
    <[ ( $op1 * $op2 ) ]>
}
```

and if I try to use it like

```
def val = 2 multiply 3
```

compiler fails with 'expected ;' error

What is the problem? How can I implement this infix-format macro?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Straight from the compiler source code:

```
namespace Nemerle.English
{
  [assembly: Nemerle.Internal.OperatorAttribute ("Nemerle.English", "and", false, 160, 161)]
  [assembly: Nemerle.Internal.OperatorAttribute ("Nemerle.English", "or", false, 150, 151)]
  [assembly: Nemerle.Internal.OperatorAttribute ("Nemerle.English", "not", true, 181, 180)]  

  macro @and (e1, e2) {
    <[ $e1 && $e2 ]>
  }

  macro @or (e1, e2) {
    <[ $e1 || $e2 ]>
  }

  macro @not (e) {
    <[ ! $e ]>
  }
```

You need to sprinkle OperatorAttributes around and it will work. Btw, OperatorAttribute is defined as follows:

```
public class OperatorAttribute : NemerleAttribute
{
  public mutable env : string;
  public mutable name : string;
  public mutable IsUnary : bool;
  public mutable left : int;
  public mutable right : int;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As usually, I found answer sooner than comunity respond :)
So, solution is to simply use special assemply level attribute which specifies the macro as binary operator:

```
namespace TestMacroLib
{
  [assembly: Nemerle.Internal.OperatorAttribute ("TestMacroLib", "multiply", false, 160, 161)]
  public macro multiply(op1, op2)
  {
    <[ ( $op1 * $op2 ) ]>
  }
}
```

Comment: Beat me by 11 seconds. Damn :)

Comment: That may also mean you should browse a little bit more before asking stuff.

Comment: You may post your question to Google Groups too: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/nemerle-en