# Nemerle OperatorAttribute parameters

Tags: macros, attributes, operators, nemerle

My question is in a comment in the following code.

```
namespace TestMacroLib
{
    [assembly: Nemerle.Internal.OperatorAttribute ("TestMacroLib", "multiply", false, 160, 161)] 
    // what does 160 and 161 represent? The parameters are "left" and "right", but that doesn't help.
    public macro multiply(op1, op2)
    {
        <[ ( $op1 * $op2 ) ]>
    }
}
```

This code sample is from:
[Infix format for Nemerle macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/223556/infix-format-for-nemerle-macro)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These numbers determine operator precedence and associativity. If the first number is smaller, the operator is left-associative, if the second — right. Operators with larger numbers have higher precedence. It looks unintuitive at first sight, but when you think more about the details of expression parsing, it makes quite a bit of sense.

Comment: I think that operators with higher numbers have higher precedence. Look at these two operators, from [Nemerle's source code](http://nemerle.googlecode.com/svn/nemerle/trunk/macros/core.n):


`[assembly: Nemerle.Internal.OperatorAttribute ("Nemerle.Core", "&&", false, 160, 161)]
[assembly: Nemerle.Internal.OperatorAttribute ("Nemerle.Core", "||", false, 150, 151)]`